# Find input/output tensors' name in Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, tensorboard

I have run this keras model based on mobilenet: https://gist.github.com/giacomobartoli/eb45ab61b43e5e47ea2a60113f9352ef
The output is a frozen graph called mobilenetv1.pb.

Now, I want to compile this model on the new [Google Vision Kit](https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/vision/).

In order to do that, I need to know the input and output tensor's name of my frozen graph (mobilenetv1.pb).
So checking TensorBoard I have the following graph:

[image]

Each node contains different input/output tensors. This is not a problem.
The point is: amongst all the nodes, which should I consider for compiling this frozen graph on the vision kit?

In other words, I need to run this script:

```
./bonnet_model_compiler.par \
--frozen_graph_path=mobilenetv1.pb \
--output_graph_path=mobilenetv1.binaryproto \
--input_tensor_name=INPUT_TENSOR_NAME \
--output_tensor_names=OUTPUT_TENSOR_NAME \
--input_tensor_size=256
```

I just need to understand which INPUT_TENSOR_NAME and OUTPUT_TENSOR_NAME are in my graph.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the graph it's not really possible to tell what's the desired input tensor and output tensor since the graph has all sorts of stuff you don't care about.

Instead, when building the graph for inference, manually name the input and output (passing `name="something"` when constructing the ops) so you know what name to use.